# Giving the right priviliges to mongodb user?

Tags: php, mongodb

'm having some real trouble changing some user rights. 
Currently, we are trying to do an eval() function in a controlled way (basically through PHP's execute function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php). 
I've enabled authentication and added some users:

```
admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
admin.addUser("superadmin", "somepass");
admin.auth("superadmin", "somepass");

bigdata = db.getSiblingDB('bigdata');
bigdata.addUser("datauser", "anotherpass");
```

How can I give the datauser the right permissions here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `eval` requires to be run by an admin user (yet another reason you shouldn't us JS in your client application) You assign those rights to the user ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#eval-shell-helper ), so the set you need are:

> readWriteAnyDatabase, userAdminAnyDatabase, dbAdminAnyDatabase and clusterAdmin

So what your looking for is how to change the user rights to have these added roles for which you can see this related SO question: [How do you change MongoDB user permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527033/how-do-you-change-mongodb-user-permissions)

Comment: So basically, I can't change the exisiting user, but have to create a new?

Comment: @Repox sorry was in a hurry, try that answer